# copying values with one to many relationship from external file in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, copy

Let say I want to copy new values from external sql file. The values are representing tables with one-to-many relationship, like: `books(book_id, title, author_id, subject), author(author_id, name, field, status)`. The `ids` are starting from `1` and incrementing. But in the database there are already data/values. So how can I copy the new values, so that they get the right id values and keeping the relationship? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to load the new data into temporary tables `new_author` and `new_book`, then insert rows from `new_author` into `author` where they didn't already exist, and then insert from `new_book` to `book`, using the ids from the newly created author records.

```
create temp table new_book(like book);
create temp table new_author(like author);

-- load data into new_book and new_author
\copy new_author from ~/new_author_file
\copy new_book from ~/new_book_file

insert into author (name, field, status)
select name, field, status
from new_author
where name not in (select name from author);

insert into book (title, author_id, subject)
select b.title, a.author_id, b.subject
from new_book b
    join new_author na on b.author_id = na.author_id
    join author a on na.name = a.name;
```

All of this assumes that `author.name` is unique, and that you know that you need to add all of the books.

Comment: Is there any way you can programmatically tell that an author already in the target DB is the same as one in the source data (and so books should be migrated to the original author in the target DB)?